# yarn run ios - Error: Cannot find module - React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, reactive-programming, simulator

So, I'm setting up new **React Native project**, and I'm trying to setup XCode simulator. I've opened my React Native project in **XCode** and in the terminal when I run "yarn run ios" from a project folder I'm getting the error "**Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename**".

```html
    My-MacBook-Pro-2:projectZero alexs$ yarn run ios
yarn run v1.13.0
$ react-native run-ios
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexs/Desktop/React/Native/projectZero/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:11:41)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/alexs/Desktop/React/Native/projectZero/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/alexs/Desktop/React/Native/projectZero/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by running:

```
yarn add @babel/runtime
```